# How to export view indexes without unique index in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

While running the below export command, its retrieving all indexes (`UNIQUE` and `NON UNIQUE` indexes)

```
exp userid=/ tables=SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME file=file.dat log=logfile.log 
rows=no indexes=yes grants=no constraints=no
```

But I want to exclude `UNIQUE index` while doing the export. Please guide.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to do this with the old `exp` program. I'm sure it can be done using the newer `expdp` and the PL/SQL package `DBMS_DATAPUMP`, but are you able to use a PL/SQL block for this task?

Answer (score 0):

The only chance I see is to create an indexfile with the option `INDEXFILE` and remove the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX...` line from the indexfile.
For details, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1019309

Please note that the old `exp` tool is not supported any more, use `expdp` instead.

As you specified `rows=no`, in case you want the metadata only, that is the table and index structure, and not the data, have a look at the package `DBMS_METADATA`.